# I have a hole in my asset when importing to unity, the model is just fine in Blender, but when I import to Unity, it has a hole in the face

Tags: export, unity

So title says it all, I have some issues exporting a Blender model into Unity. It looks perfect in Blender, but I have issues when exporting to Unity, mainly that hole in his face.

[image]

Hoping someone can help me :)

[Link to Blender file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/vy5m0he92xsz16m/shapeshifterfinal.fbx/file)

Comment: it may have to do with the normals, go in Edit mode, select all and Shift N to recalculate, but your topology is not very good so it may not fix everything

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the normals, go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate.